# use of CTTelephonyNetworkInfo

Tags: swift

I want to know the quality of the network,
I see the CTTelephonyNetwork but i don't know how to use this command

I Want to communicate with SIM 808 module : 
-  I want to send data to the sim and receive data from the sim
Thanks you

Comment: There is no way to get information about cellular signal strength and there is no way to access data from SIM card

Comment: How can I acces data from SIM card ?

Comment: You can't access data from SIM card.